# C++ template singleton base class for deep level inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

So I have a simple singleton template base class (minified for question purposes):

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton {
public:
    static T& instance() {
        static T me;
        return me;
    }
};
```

Now I want to have a "Base class that's a singleton":

```
class Base : public Singleton<Base> {
public:
    void print() { std::cout << &instance() << std::endl; }
}
```

What I want now is deriving children classes from this base class, which are their own singletons:

```
class A : public Base {
    // ...
}

class B : public Base {
    // ...
}
```

Of course if I do this

```
A::instance().print();
B::instance().print();
```

I get the same address in both cases. Is there a way to accomplish this?

In case you're wondering what for: I want to program a `ResourceManager` base class which is being inherited by a class `ImageManager`, a class 'AudioManager', etc. And I'd like them not to share actually the same instance, but still having only one instance per manager...

Comment: I don't understand. Why the classes at all? `template <typename T> T& instance() { ... }`.

Comment: you're not the first person to make a templated singleton class but I hope you're the last (I'm sure you won't be). Take 2 steps back and design it away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to make Base a template and pass that to `Singleton`, then inherit from `Base<A>` if you wish to achieve this. Or, if you want Base to be a Singleton *and* A/B to be a Singleton, then they will have to inherit from `Singleton<A>`, `Singleton<B>` in addition to `Base`.

But dear lord, man, Singletons are a curse on you and your children for a hundred generations. Why would you do that to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to make Base a non singleton class and then make Class A and Class B singletons that instantiate the Base class.  This gives you flexibility and follows the object oriented principle of favoring composition over inheritance http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html

Because of the static members required on a Singleton you cannot directly inherit from a Singleton Class.  Composition will serve you better in this situation, and most others as well.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer, because it is the answer to the question, but I think I'm gonna go with your approach... The only thing I don't really get is how to 'reuse' methods of the `Base` class. I would need to wrap the calls in child class methods, wouldn't I?

Comment: To reuse them you'd refactor the base methods so that you won't need to subclass the Base class at all.  In Class A you'd have an instance of BaseClass, the same in Class B.  You could also add make BaseClass a singleton if you really needed only one to exist, but I'd stay away from that if you can avoid it.

Comment: Yes. So for instance if I want to call `A::print()` I'd have to implement this static method to call `me->baseObject->print()`, right?

Comment: Exactly.  A call to A::print could pass unique information to the baseObject->print method. A::print() would call me->baseObject->print(instance).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I see for when a base class must have something from its child is using Child as an argument to Base as follow:

```
template< bool val, class TrueT, class FlaseT >
struct If {
    typedef TrueT type;
};
template< class TrueT, class FalseT >
struct If< false, TrueT, FalseT > {
    typedef FalseT type;
};
template< class DerivedT = void >
class Base {
public:
    typedef typename If<std::is_same<DerivedT, void>::value,
        Base<DerivedT>, DerivedT>::type this_type;
    static this_type& instance() {
        this_type me;
        return me;
    }

public:
    void test() {}
};
class A : public Base<A> {
public:
    void print() {}
};
class B : public Base<B> {
public:
    void print() {}
};
Base<>::instance().test();
B::instance().print();
A::instance().print();
```